# Log4j in spark2-shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am running one of spark script through `spark2-shell -i` option.

I want to redirect logs generated to a file using log4j framework.

Command that I used to run:

```
spark2-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client -i audit.scala --conf spark.driver.args="PROD sample.txt" --files /bigdata/datalakes/app/log/log4j.properties#log4j.properties --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/bigdata/datalakes/app/log/log4j.properties'
```

And this is content of `/bigdata/datalakes/app/log/log4j.properties` :

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    #Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
    #log4j.appender.file.File=/bigdata/datalakes/app/log/spark.log
    log4j.appender.file.File=/bigdata/datalakes/app/log/spark.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply this as configuration option to spark.

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=/bigdata/datalakes/app/log/log4j.properties" 

--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=/bigdata/datalakes/app/log/log4j.properties"
```

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !

Comment: With this configuration also, logs are displayed on console.